# Flink - Async IO operator for series of API calls

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are using an async IO operator to make calls to external APIs. We had only one api call per event until now. But, we have a requirement where we would have to introduce multiple API calls for every event. Using threads within the operator and making the calls in a series did provide a solution but does that defeat the purpose of using Async IO?. Would using threads cause any other issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are now actually using `asyncIO` as it was intended. `asyncIO` does not spawn any threads on is own but expects user code to do so directly or indirectly.

There are two main use cases:
1) Using external callbacks where the employed library returns the result. For example, using reactive API of mongodb.
2) Maintaining a custom thread pool (for example, with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`) and using it to implement async operations manually.

You are using the second approach.

Without using any of them, `asyncIO` is just a slow `map`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I did verify this with a thread profiler and the newly spawned threads handling the series of API calls for one event did go into the IO state. I wanted to find out if I would break anything. Hence, the question.

Comment: IO state is exactly what you want to have. IO state indicates that it's waiting for network traffic to arrive. Waiting state would mean it's idling (waiting for Flink to call it). You could increase your thread pool more until you see a few idling threads (then you are near the sweet spot).

Comment: thanks a lot for this. Will surely try it out! As an aside, let's say we have to use the result of one API call in another call that follows it, would using a single thread still make Flink treat it as a thread waiting for IO when it is executing a call and hence free up processing time for other events.

Comment: No Flink is not inspecting the thread state and does not know what the user code does. `asyncIO` is just collecting the output of your async calls, puts them in order (if so configured), and ensures that watermarks are correctly inserted. There is no other black magic. So if you want the two calls to be processed independently, you have to use two chained `asyncIO`.

Comment: Thanks @Arvid Heise